# cambio en listas python

Tags: python-3.x

buenas y gracias de antemano por la ayuda, tego un problema en un ejercicio y como soy nuevo en esto a veces se me complica
lo que necesito hacer basicamente es cambiar un elemento de una lista por otro elemento de otra lista, por ejemplo
tengo una lista de elementos positivos y otra de negativos y si por error el usuario ingresa un elemento negativo en la lista de positivos y viceversa, tengo que cambiar el valor del positivo al negativo y del negativo al positivo, tal que asi
positivos = [1,2,-3]
negativos = [-1,-2,3]
reordenando deberia quedar asi:
positivos = [1,2,3]
negativos = [-1,-2,-3]
hasta donde llegue en el codigo es a esto

```
pos = [-1, 2, -3]
neg = [1, -2, 3]

for m in range(len(pos)):
    for b in range(len(neg)):
        if m < 0 and b > 0 and pos[m] == neg[b]:
            pos[m] = b
            neg[b] = m
print(pos)
print(neg)
```

y el resultado es que imprime lo mismo sin hacer ninguna modificacion

Answer (score 0):

La solución es buscar en una lista (positivos, por ejemplo) los valores fuera de orden (negativos, en este caso).

Cuando encuentras un valor fuera de orden, recorres la otra lista (negativos) buscando un elemento fuera de orden (positivo). Cuando lo encuentras, intercambias entre ambas listas.

En Python intercambiar dos elementos `a` y `b` es tan simple como:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Lo que pasa es que Python *primero* evalua todas las expresiones del lado derecho (el valor actual de `a` y `b`) y luego hace las asignaciones.

Nota: El código sólo funciona si ambas listas tienen el mismo número de elementos mal asignados.

#### Demo

```
pos = [-1, 2, -3]
neg = [1, -2, 3]

for m_pos in range(len(pos)):
    if pos[m_pos] < 0: # Valor negativo en la lista positiva.
        for b_neg in range(len(neg)):
            if neg[b_neg] >= 0: # Valor positivo en la lista negativa.
                pos[m_pos], neg[b_neg] = neg[b_neg], pos[m_pos]
print(pos)
print(neg)
```

produce:

```
[2, 1, 3]
[-1, -3, -2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Solución Pitónica

Podemos hacer lo mismo en forma más compacta usando comprensión de listas. La idea es crear dos nuevas listas que cumplan la condición exigida.

```
pos_filter = [x for x in pos + neg if x >= 0]
neg_filter = [x for x in pos + neg if x < 0]
```

Si tenemos dos listas, `pos + neg` es una lista que los elementos de ambas.

A continuación recorro la lista temporal (`x for x in pos + neg`) seleccionando sólo los positivos con `if x >= 0`. Estos elementos se incorporan en una nueva lista (`[x ...]`).

#### Demo

```
pos = [-1, 2, -3]
neg = [1, -2, 3]

pos_filter = [x for x in pos + neg if x >= 0]
neg_filter = [x for x in pos + neg if x < 0]

print(pos_filter)
print(neg_filter)
```

produce:

```
[2, 1, 3]
[-1, -3, -2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la ayuda a los conceptos brindados, me sirvieron bastantes, le realice algunas modificaciones para que no altere el orden al hacer los cambios
pos = [-1, 8, -3]
neg = [5, -2, 25]

for i in range(len(pos)):

```
    for j in range(len(neg)):
        if pos[i] < 0:
            if neg[j] >= 0:
                pos[i], neg[j] = neg[j], pos[i]
                pos.reverse()
```

print(pos)
print(neg)
reproduciendo
[5, 8, 25]
[-1, -2, -3]